# Update query if alreay exist based on column value in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to update query if duplicate column value found in mysql

```
INSERT INTO receipt ( amount, bill_no) VALUES('100','1') 
ON DUPLICATE  bill_no='1' UPDATE amount='100'
```

My Actual Query is

```
insert into ig_receipt_payment 
    ( party, local_party_bill, date, amount, mode, description, options, type, job, bill_no, production_code ) 
values 
( '$_POST[worker]', '', '".date_merge("date")."', '$_POST[kooli_amount]', '', '$_POST[kooli_remark]', 'loading', 'credit', 'loading', '$_GET[id]', '' ) 
ON DUPLICATE   bill_no
update ig_receipt_payment set party = '$_POST[party]', local_party_bill = '$_POST[local_party_bill]', date = '".date_merge("date")."', amount = '$_POST[kooli_amount]',  description = '$_POST[kooli_remark]'
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: try using `ON DUPLICATE  bill_no UPDATE amount=values('100')`

Comment: Thank you so much @Suchit. But its not working..

Answer (score 1):

First, I would simplify your query using `values` instead of repeating the constant and fix the syntax errors:

```
insert into ig_receipt_payment( party, local_party_bill, date, amount, mode, description, options, type, job, bill_no, production_code ) 
    values ( '$_POST[worker]', '', '".date_merge("date")."', '$_POST[kooli_amount]', '', '$_POST[kooli_remark]', 'loading', 'credit', 'loading', '$_GET[id]', '' ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       party = VALUES(party), local_party_bill = values(local_party_bill),
       date = VALUES(date), amount = VALUES(amount),
       description = VALUES(description);
```

Then, you need a unique index/constraint to define the duplicates.  I am guessing this is on the column `bill_no`:

```
create unique index unq_ig_receipt_payment_billno on ig_receipt_payment( bill_no)
```